# Group by só retorna 1 resultado

Tags: mysql, group-by

Estou com um problema com minha `query` no MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    *
    FROM `campeonatos` 
    INNER JOIN `jogos`
    ON `campeonatos`.`camp_id`=`jogos`.`campeonato_id` 
    WHERE `jogos`.`inicio` > "2017-10-30 00:00:00" 
    ORDER BY `campeonatos`.`camp_nome` ASC
```

O problema que ele agrupa e só retorna o primeiro registro.
Eu gostaria que ele agrupasse pelo campeonato e retornasse algo mais ou menos assim:

```
Campeonato : 888
São Paulo x Flamengo
São Paulo x Flamengo

Campeonato 889
São Paulo x Flamengo
São Paulo x Flamengo
```

Comment: Tem como postar o `group by` tentado?

Comment: Lucas para agrupar, tem que usar o `GROUP BY`... Mas para ajudarmos melhor, poste o script de criação e dados: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33932e/1